# Dynamic list properties in spring

Tags: spring

I've been googling this for about a hour, with little success.

Suppose that in my `web.xml` I have :

```
<Parameter name="hibernate.websitespecific.entityscanpackages" value="com.mystuff.pojo.entities, com.mystuff.otherpackage.pojo.entities"/>
```

and in my spring context config I have:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.mystuff.somethingelse.pojo</value>
                <value>com.mystuff.weirdbeans.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
[...]
```

I'd like to add `hibernate.websitespecific.entityscanpackages` to the list of packages to scan in a clean way. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference context parameters in bean definition files using SPEL:

For example:

```
<property name="foo" value="#{contextParameters.fooParamName}" />
```

**Edit**

To merge the both package list:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="#{contextParameters.paramName + ',pk1,pk2,pk3'}"/>
```

or

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="#{contextParameters.paramName + ',' + T(org.springframework.util.StringUtils).collectionToCommaDelimitedString(@someList)}" />

    <util:list id="someList">
      <value>pk1</value>
      <value>pk2</value>
     ...
    </util:list>
```

Comment: Ah! I see, you don't know how to merge the Strings. Use + operator on spel or T(StringUtils).collectionToCommaDelimitedString(@yourList)

Comment: Now the answer makes sense